# Como posso resolver esse erro (System.FormatException) C# Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Por que quando eu apago todas as informações mesmo já convertidas para o tipo double condidas dentro do textBox ele me retornar esse erro (System.FormatException: 'A cadeia de caracteres de entrada não estava em um formato correto.)?

//Declarações de variáveis
double JurosBV = 0.0402, JurosItau = 0.0342, JurosBradesco = 0.027;
double PrecoVeiculo = 0.0, ValorEntrada = 0.0;

```
    public void txtPreco_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrecoVeiculo = Convert.ToDouble(txtPreco.Text);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Muito provável que este erro esteja ocorrendo quando você apaga todos os valores da txtPreco e o código tenta converter vazio para um double, o que acaba resultando no erro.

Talvez para evitar que o erro ocorra você possa adicionar uma validação antes de converter o valor.

```
private void txtPreco_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPreco.Text))
    {
        PrecoVeiculo = 0;
        return;
    }

    PrecoVeiculo = Convert.ToDouble(txtPreco.Text);
}
```

Outra validação que você pode estar implementando é para verificar se o txtPreco contém apenas dígitos, exceto vírgulas/ponto.

```
if (txtPreco.Text.Any(x => !char.IsDigit(x) && x != ',' && x != '.'))
{
    return;
}
```